# Differentiating between boundedness and finiteness.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am a little puzzled by some notations in optimization community. Is there anyone who can explain why $f_1:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a finite valueed but $f_2:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is not?? I have never have this kind of notations. For function $f_1$ I always calculated limit when $x\rightarrow \infty$ and nobody said you can't as infinity is not a member of real values.

Can anyone clarify this for me?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused about what this has to do with any of the tags you've added.

Comment: It doesn't have the flags I wanted. So I was forced to add these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f_1(x) = L$ is a shorthand notation for the property that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a value $N$ such that for all $x > N, |f_1(x)-L| < \varepsilon$.  It doesn't actually make use of an infinite value $\infty$.

But broadly speaking, what you see is the distinction between arbitrarily large and infinite.  If we define $f_1(x) = x$ on the reals $\mathbb{R}$, then $f_1$ always takes in a finite real value and outputs a finite real value.  That value may be arbitrarily large (in either the positive or negative direction), but it is never infinite, because there are no infinite values in $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, if we define $f_2(x) = 1/x$ on the reals, then $f_2$ can take in a finite real value (namely $0$) that does not produce as output a finite real value.  We can either say that $f_2(0)$ is undefined, or (if we specify $f_2: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$), we can instead say that $f_2(0) = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I think it clarified my confusion :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that we don't normally consider $\infty$ to be a number: we can take limits in $\mathbb{R}$, for example, as things get larger and larger, and we say that they "approach $\infty$"...however, we never say that they reach it. So, $f_1:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is finite-valued because for any real vector $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f_1(\vec{x})$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, which doesn't actually contain anything we might refer to as "$\infty$" ($\infty$ is not contained in the codomain of $f_1$).

$f_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, on the other hand, includes something we are calling infinity: so, we have a value that is outside of $\mathbb{R}$, and there might actually be an $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $f_2(\vec{x})=\infty$. ($\infty$ is contained in the codomain of $f_2$).